# valueChangeListener is invoked on submit without changing options in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

In my page I have selectonemenu and I have noticed that when I click the pagination of datatable, valueChangeListener method is getting invoked without actually changing values or options in selectonemenu.

How is this happening and how could I prevent this from happening as I need to invoke valueChangeListener method only if user changes values in selectonemenu.

Thanks and appreciate any help.

Regards

Here is my code for selectonemenu

**Update1**

```
<ice:selectOneMenu value="#{list.selectedItem}"
            partialSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{list.val}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{list.selectItems}" />
                </ice:selectOneMenu>
```

And bean method

```
   public void val(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            logger.info("1");
            selectedValue = event.getNewValue().toString();
}
```

Values are added like

```
public void loadItems(){
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("1", "One"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "Two"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("3", "Three"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("4", "Four")); 

}
```

And method is called as follows

```
 public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
        if (selectItems == null) {
            loadItems;

        }
        return selectItems;
    }
```

Comment: please post code. it is hard to diagnose without it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSF `valueChangeListener` is **in no way** related to the client-side events. It is a server-side event which will be invoked when the *submitted* value differs from the *initial* value.

The first item of your list has a value of `1`, so when the user doesn't change the dropdown, the submitted value will be `1`. If you don't want the `valueChangeListener` to be invoked, then you need to ensure that the initial value also equals to `1`. That is the value behind `#{list.selectedItem}"`. Initialize it to the same value as the first item during bean's construction/initialization.

```
this.selectedItem = "1";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC that worked. So is this the best practice to initialize the same value in constructor or some other better approach exists?

Comment: I have one more doubt, I could see value when submitted and initial value are same. When page loads before I start navigating using pagination, drop down is say 1 and when I click pagination, submitted value is also 1. So how does valueChangeListener is invoked? But like you mentioned when I initialize with this.selectedItem="1"; then valueChangeListener doesn't gets invoked.  Little confused with this behavior.

Comment: What exactly do you need the `valueChangeListener` method for, after all? You don't seem to be interested in the value change, but only in the submitted value. For that you can also just do the desired job in the bean's action method.

Comment: I am using valueChangeListener for refreshing the datatable if user changes an option in selectonemenu. Initially datatable is loaded with default value and that value is same as the initial value in selectonemenu.

Comment: You can also just get currently selected value in action method of pagination.

Comment: Yes initially selectedItem is null if I do not initialize in constructor.

Comment: I have one more question in this regard. Which is the correct place to call the method of populating selectonemenu values? should it be in constructor or like this?     public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
        if (selectItems == null) {
            loadItems();
        }
        return selectItems;
    }

Comment: In constructor or postconstruct.