# Show drop down box with values when select value from another dropdown

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I need to show a new drop down box upon selecting a value from another drop down box which is already available in the page. First drop down is already available in the page and second will be hidden based on boolean value I am getting from Bean class.

The problem is the hidden drop down is not visible until I refresh the page. When I refresh the page, then only I can see the hidden drop down box. When I unselect another value from first drop down box, the second dropdown should be hidden which is also happening, but I have to refresh the page.

See my code below for reference:

`instrumentDetails.xhtml`

```
<!-- First drop down -->
        <h:outputText id="product_Group"
            value="#{msg.instrument_add_edit_product_group}" escape="false" />
        <a4j:region>
            <h:selectOneMenu
                value="#{instrumentBean.instrumentData.productGroupId}"
                valueChangeListener="#{instrumentBean.populateProductTypeByServiceProvider}"
                style="width:140px" styleClass="dropDown">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0"
                    itemLabel="#{msg['gobal.select.default.label']}" />
                <f:selectItems var="productGroupItem"
                    itemValue="#{productGroupItem.id}"
                    itemLabel="#{productGroupItem.label}"
                    value="#{referenceMaster.productGroupLabelKeyList}" />
                <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"   render="productTypeListInstrument,servList,showServiceId"
                    execute="@this" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:region>

<!-- Second drop down -->       
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" id ="showServiceId" rendered="#{instrumentBean.showService}">
        <h:outputText id="serviceId" value="#{msg.instrument_add_edit_service}"
            escape="false" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{instrumentBean.instrumentData.service}"
            style="width:140px" styleClass="dropDown" >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Mobile" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Telephone" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="ISDN BRI" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

`InstrumentBean.java`

```
private boolean showService;

    public void populateProductTypeByServiceProvider(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        try {
            Integer rowindex = new Integer(event.getNewValue().toString());
            if (!CommonUtil.isBlankInteger(instrumentData
                    .getServiceProviderId())
                    && !CommonUtil.isBlankInteger(rowindex)) {

                int productGroupId = rowindex.intValue();

                List<LabelKeyTO> labelKeyTOList = findProductsByGroupAndServiceProvider(
                        productGroupId, instrumentData.getServiceProviderId());

                Collections.sort(labelKeyTOList);
                this.productTypeDetailList = labelKeyTOList;
                setDefaultDetailsListSerRate();
                defaultServiceTable();

            } else {
                if (CommonUtil.isBlankInteger(instrumentData
                        .getServiceProviderId())) {
                    this.instrumentData.setProductGroupId(0);
                }
                this.instrumentData.setProductTypeId(0);
                setDefaultDetailsListProdSerRate();
                defaultServiceTable();
            }

            if(rowindex == 1){
                showService = true;
            }else if(rowindex == 2){
                showService = true;
            }else{
                showService = false;
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.instrumentData.setProductTypeId(0);
            setDefaultDetailsListProdSerRate();
            defaultServiceTable();
            String reasonFailure = e.getMessage();
            validationMessage(reasonFailure, reasonFailure, reasonFailure,
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already have implemented mechanism for re-rendering second drop down box when value in first box is changed (`<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="showServiceId" execute="@this" />`). You need only check if rendering condition for parent of second drop down box working correctly: `rendered="#{instrumentBean.showService}"` a probably fix it.

Comment: @VasilLukach..  Dear Vasil, Thanks for your answer. As you can see above in my code, I have already used  : rendered="#{instrumentBean.showService}"  in my second drop down. But it is shown only after refreshing the page. This is the issue.  Kindly suggest on the same.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932810/valuechangelistener-is-invoked-on-submit-without-changing-options-in-selectoneme `ValueChangeListener` are only invoked on submit. You need to use AJAX to change the value server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using 'listener'.

I have added the code in first dropdown for listener. Please see below the updated code :

```
<!-- Product Group -->

<h:outputText id="product_Group"
    value="#{msg.instrument_add_edit_product_group}" escape="false" />
<a4j:region>
    <h:selectOneMenu
        value="#{instrumentBean.instrumentData.productGroupId}"
        valueChangeListener="#{instrumentBean.populateProductTypeByServiceProvider}"
        style="width:140px" styleClass="dropDown" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0"
            itemLabel="#{msg['gobal.select.default.label']}" />
        <f:selectItems var="productGroupItem"
            itemValue="#{productGroupItem.id}"
            itemLabel="#{productGroupItem.label}"
            value="#{referenceMaster.productGroupLabelKeyList}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"   render="productTypeListInstrument,servList" execute="@this" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change"  listener="#{instrumentBean.onChangeProductGroup}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:region>
```

Thanks for your answers guys.